# Keeping layout in new activity

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity

In my layout "as below". I want to start another activity as soon as flipper is done and continue with same state of view in new activity.
Basically I want to keep some part of layout to be static while other parts animated and have its own activity.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:minHeight="50dp"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/logo" />

</RelativeLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <ViewFlipper
        android:id="@+id/viewFlipper1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

        <include
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            layout="@layout/first" />

        <include
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            layout="@layout/country" />

    </ViewFlipper>

</RelativeLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: when you navigate from 1st to 2nd in second setContentView(layout of 1st activity)

Comment: I have try that, but it resets the view, I want to be able to keep the same state of the flipperview.